# calculating time taken to create n threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

I am trying to create 1000 threads so that I can know how much time it is taking to create them. Im using pthreads. But Im getting segmentation fault: 11. 
Googling it tells me that it might the case of using too much memory but I doubt it to be possible reason.

Any pointers as to what might be the reason ?

Code:

```
int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
   int *i;          // Matti's answer below:  ... = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
   *i = 0;
   while( *i < 100)
   {
     pthread_t thread_id;
     puts("Connection accepted");
     if( pthread_create( &thread_id , NULL , connection_handler ,  (void*) &i) < 0)
     {
        error("could not create thread");
        return 1;
     }

     //pthread_detach(thread_id);
     *i = *i + 1;
   }

    return 0;
}

void *connection_handler(void *i)
{
  sleep(1);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi @sad - it's best not to fix the code in the question, as it removes context and makes Matti's answer seem irrelevant.  I've edited it to be a comment.  Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem would be the fact that you're dereferencing a pointer that was never initialized:

```
int *i;
*i = 0;
```

What's wrong with just `int i;`?

Answer (score 1):

> Googling it tells me that it might the case of using too much memory

On Ubuntu 15.10, and with g++ v5.2.1, the

```
 default stack size per thread is 8M bytes
```

Thus, 1000 * 8M could be as much as 8G bytes.

My older Dell has only 4G bytes, total, of dram.  I think this might mean that more than 1/2 of the thread stacks will roll into/out of the swap partition.

Not sure if you want to spend any time measuring that nor worrying about it.

---

By the way, threads context switches are very slow, about 3 orders of magnitude slower than function/method calls ... use them wisely.

on my older Dell - using c++_11 thread and std::mutex:

```
     50 nano seconds per std::mutex lock and std::mutex::unlock
~12,000 nano seconds per context switch enforced by std::mutex
```

---

What I did not see in your code snippet above is ::pthread_exit().  You possibly could do a reasonable measure of create and exit ... maybe you intended to also exit each thread before you run out of memory?

---

update - getting thread stack size using posix

```
void stackShow() // posix thread stack size
{
   pthread_attr_t tattr;  
   int stat = pthread_attr_init (&tattr); 
   assert(0 == stat);

   size_t size; 
   stat = pthread_attr_getstacksize(&tattr, &size); 
   assert(0 == stat);

   std::cout << "  ----------------------------------------------------\n"
             << "  getstacksize: (" << stat << ")   size is " << size 
             << "\n\n";

   stat = pthread_attr_destroy(&tattr);
   assert(0 == stat);
}
```

Comment: I think there is a way to reduce the default thread stack size ... sorry, I can not remember it at the moment.

Comment: Imagine your context switch time is similar to 12,000 nanoseconds.  How long would you expect it takes for each of the 1000 threads to run once, to finish initializing, to get to the 'ready-to-run' state?